# Salesforce - Does Schema class describe methods cached at salesforce end?

Tags: security, salesforce, apex

I have a requirement where I want to check permission for salesforce custom object & fields before every DML. as a solution, I have implemented my own versions of DML statements like Util.insert, Util.update etc.

In those methods, I am doing permission checks using Salesforce 'Schema Describe' methods.

I was trying to find information about internal working of these methods, If salesforce cache this information for single execution context or caching should be handled at my end for better performance.

I could not find any information about this in their official documentation.

appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually if you want but there is this project on git that utilizes an access controller to test for FLS and CRUD issues.  We implemented it and it works very well.

https://github.com/CodeScience/CSUtils/wiki/Using-Security-Coding-Library-(ESAPI)